# Extract predefined URL text (starts with the same prefix) into an Array

Tags: arrays, regex, vba, outlook

I have files URLs text like these examples:
http://xxxxx.pdf   http://xxxxxxxxxxx.doc http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.xls
The delimiter between each URL is not a space, it may be separated by `vbTab` , `vbLf` or what ever.
But in all cases the URLs start with the same prefix "**http**:" and end with a **dot+three characters**.
I need to extract these predefined URLs into an Array to manipulate it later.
I made the below code as a workaround, by using two arrays and also I had to start looping from the second element from the first array because I found there is extra "http" on the second array.
My question, Is there another neater code?

```
Sub Split_URLs_to_Array()

  Dim wDoc As Word.Document, rngSel As String
  Dim arrS, arrD, i As Long
  
  Set wDoc = Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
  
  rngSel = Trim(wDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Text)

  arrS = Split(rngSel, "http")
  
  ReDim arrD(0 To UBound(arrS))
  
   For i = 1 To UBound(arrS)
       arrD(i) = "http" & arrS(i)
     Debug.Print arrD(i)
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code looks neat enough. Does it work? You might also want to trim your array entries: `arrD(i) = "http" & Trim(arrS(i))`

Comment: @Super Symmetry , I will leave it may be there is a better one or regex equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You asked (yesterday) about a way to extract URLs from a string, separated by no any separator... The next function will do it:

```
Function SplitByStartOfString(strTxt As String, strDelim As String) As Variant
  Dim arr: arr = Split(strTxt, strDelim)
  
  arr(0) = "@#$%^": arr = filter(arr, "@#$%^", False) 'eliminate the first empty element
  SplitByStartOfString = Split(strDelim & Join(arr, "|" & strDelim), "|")
End Function
```

It can be tested in the next way:

```
Sub testSplitByStartOfString()
   Dim x As String: x = "https://myurl1/x.pdfhttps://myurl2/y.xlsxhttps://myurl3/z.docx"
   Dim arr
   arr = SplitByStartOfString(x, "https:")
   Debug.Print Join(arr, "||") 'just to visually see the array result.
End Sub
```

Of course, you can use what strings you know, the delimiter will be the common prefix of each of them...

And end of line separators or `VbTab` exists, the above code will also work, but **these separators will be included of the end of the string**. Which, for URL in Outlook will not count. They will only be arranged using the respective separator.

1.1 Another function, using `FilterXML` may be the next one:

```
Function splitXMLByStartOfString(strText As String, strDelim As String) As Variant
    Dim XML As String: XML = "<t><s>" & VBA.Replace(strText, strDelim, "</s><s>" & strDelim) & "</s></t>"
    splitXMLByStartOfString = Application.FilterXML(XML, "//s[position()>1]")  'nodes starting from the second one...
    'splitXMLByStartOfString = Application.FilterXML(XML, "//s[count(node())>0]")   'another working way (all not empty nodes)
    'splitXMLByStartOfString = Application.FilterXML(XML, "//s[starts-with(., '" & strDelim & "')]") 'working way, too (nodes starting with strDelim)
End Function
```

It can be tested using the next sub:

```
Sub TestFilterXMLHttp()
   Dim x As String: x = "https://myurl1/x.pdfhttps://myurl2/y.xlsxhttps://myurl3/z.docx"
   Dim arr: arr = splitXMLByStartOfString(x, "https:") 'It returns a 2D, 1 column array...
  
   Debug.Print Join(Application.Transpose(arr), "||")
End Sub
```

The above function works well and fast, but in Excel. The question does not mention that it should be used in Outlook VBA (but I knew about that...). So, the next solution uses an automation from Outlook, and use `Excel.Application` it this way. This version needs an Excel session open, but it can be easily adapted to open a new one if nothing open:

```
Function splitXMLByStartOfString(strText As String, strDelim As String, objEx As Object) As Variant
   
    Dim XML As String: XML = "<t><s>" & VBA.Replace(strText, strDelim, "</s><s>" & strDelim) & "</s></t>"
    splitXMLByStartOfString = objEx.FilterXML(XML, "//s[position()>1]")  'nodes starting from the second one...
    'splitXMLByStartOfString = Application.FilterXML(XML, "//s[count(node())>0]")   'another working way (all not empty nodes)
    'splitXMLByStartOfString = Application.FilterXML(XML, "//s[starts-with(., '" & strDelim & "')]") 'working way, too (nodes starting with strDelim)
End Function
```

And the sub to test it, using the above mentioned automation:

```
Sub TestFilterXMLHttp()
   Dim objEx As Object: Set objEx = GetObject(, "Excel.application")
   Dim x As String: x = "https://myurl1/x.pdfhttps://myurl2/y.xlsxhttps://myurl3/z.docx"
   Dim arr: arr = splitXMLByStartOfString(x, "https:", objEx) 'It returns a 2D, 1 column array...
  
   Debug.Print Join(objEx.Transpose(arr), "||")
End Sub
```

2. Extracting an array from string elements separated by one from more supposed separators can be extracted using the next function:

```
Function extractFromStringSep(strText As String) As Variant
   Dim arrC: arrC = Array(vbTab, vbLf) 'you can extend the supposed separators...
   Dim El
   
   For Each El In arrC
        If InStr(strText, El) > 0 Then
            extractFromStringSep = Split(strText, El): Exit Function
        End If
   Next El
End Function
```

Of course, the string to be extracted **must NOT** contain the supposed separators...

It can be tested like in the next sub:

```
Sub TestextractFromStringSep()
   Dim x As String: x = "https://myurl1/x.pdf" & vbTab & "https://myurl2/y.xlsx" & vbTab & "https://myurl3/z.docx"
          'x = "https://myurl1/x.pdf" & vbLf & "https://myurl2/y.xlsx" & vbLf & "https://myurl3/z.docx"
   Dim arr
   arr = extractFromStringSep(x)
   Debug.Print Join(arr, "||") 'just to visually see the array result.
End Sub
```

3. And a last version, also allowing **part of the url string** as separator (only for didactic purpose):

```
Function extractFromStrAndSep(strText As String, strDelim As String) As Variant
     Dim arrC: arrC = Array(vbTab, vbLf, "myur") 'you can extend the supposed separators...
     Dim El
     
     For Each El In arrC
        If InStr(strText, El & strDelim) > 0 Then
            extractFromStrAndSep = Split(strText, El & strDelim): Exit Function
        End If
   Next El
End Function
```

Tested with the next (adapted) sub:

```
Sub TestextractFromStrAndSep()
   Dim x As String: 'x = "https://myurl1/x.pdf" & vbTab & "https://myurl2/y.xlsx" & vbTab & "https://myurl3/z.docx"
          'x = "https://myurl1/x.pd" & vbLf & "https://myurl2/y.xlsx" & vbLf & "https://myurl3/z.docx"
          x = "https://myurl1/x.pd" & "myur" & "https://myurl2/y.xlsx" & "myur" & "https://myurl3/z.docx"
   Dim arr
   arr = extractFromStrAndSep(x, "https:")
   Debug.Print Join(arr, "||") 'just to visually see the array result.
End Sub
```

Comment: I tested `Function SplitByStartOfString` and now it works correctly even with separator between each url , and also tested `Function extractFromStringSep` and works perfectly.

Comment: @Soma I edited the answer and placed a last version able to deal with a separator which can be part of the strings to be split... `Function SplitByStartOfString` may work with separator, of course,  **but** the separator **is included in the extracted strings**. In the used examples, the extracted url strings will be positioned on top of each other...

Comment: @Soma I edited again the answer and placed another interesting function (using `FilterXML`)...

Comment: I tried the newest function `splitXMLByStartOfString` but I got this error (Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method) at this line `splitXMLByStartOfString = Application.FilterXML(XML, "//s[position()>1]")` , I think that is because I am using Office 2016

Comment: @Soma AFAIK, `FilterXML` is available since Office 2013. Did you try it **with the testing sub I provided**? It does not accept Tab or end lines inside the tag...

Comment: Yes I tried it with the testing sub you provided and it did not work inside outlook module , but when I tried it inside excel workbook , it worked correctly. I do not know why !

Comment: @Soma I know (now) why... `FilterXML` is an Excel function only. I've  just played with Excel VBA to show an (interesting, on my taste) alternative to that function. You cannot use it in Outlook. Except the case of trying an Excel automation from there...

Comment: @Soma I placed another pair (function and testing sub) able to work from Outlook. Using Excel automation, as I said above...

Comment: I tried your latest sub and works perfectly, But I think for automation `Dim x As String` should be a Range in excel.

Comment: @Soma You can adapt it as you need. But that function processes **strings**. You can transform a range in a string as you need. Otherwise, the function waiting for a string will raise an error... If it is **a single cell** you may use `CStr(rng.value)`... Of course, where the range/cell is `rng`.

Comment: @Soma `FilterXML` is a very fast and versatile function. Apropos, it is able to place a discontinuous range in an array without iteration, as you required some time ago. But it has a limitation of characters number to be processed. Otherwise, some slices of maximum 32767 characters (its limitation) can be used and build the range by iteration between them. Which is not without (any) iteration, anymore... It is only  a matter of being possible, let us say, only for didactic purpose.

Comment: Please can you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990568/what-is-the-difference-benefit-between-using-application-function-and-workshe