# What is the difference/benefit between using (Application.function) and (WorksheetFunction.function)?

Tags: excel, vba

In Fact, I was trying to use a range as the criteria of AutoFilter.

So, I have used the transpose function to convert the range to one dimensional array.

Then I have used this snippet of code:

`arr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rng.value)`

Also found that using `Application` instead of  `WorksheetFunction` is the same result.

`arr = Application.Transpose(rng.value)`

Apart from Intellisence suggestions, Is there any difference/benefit between using (Application.w
function) and  (WorksheetFunction.function) ?

Comment: `Worksheetfunction.function` raises a run-time error if the function fails (eg Match() fails to find a match) but `Application.Function` returns an error value.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063214/how-to-error-handle-1004-error-with-worksheetfunction-vlookup/18064104#18064104

Comment: There can also be slight differences in behaviour with some functions. For example `application.countif` will allow you to pass an array/multi-cell range as criteria, whereas the `worksheetfunction` version won't.

Comment: Both above answers are correct! I would say that `WorksheetFunction` raise a **fatal error**, stopping on the respective yellow code line and `Application` does not. I mean, using `Vlookup`, `Match` etc. will stop the code on the respective code line and using `Dim x As Variant` followed by `x = Application.Vlookup("code",A2:F1000,3, False)` will not raise any error.  For that case `If not IsError(x) Then`. Or a litle more elaborate, you can use `x = Application.IFERROR(Vlookup("code",A2:F1000,3, False)`, "not Existing")`. If x = "not Existing" then` (maybe) execute a new `Vlookup` on Sheet2

Comment: In case of `Match`, you may try matching **two arrays** and it will return a third array: `myArray3 = Application.IfError(Application.match(MyArray1, myArray2, 0), "x")`. You may see the matching one, simple using `Debug.Print Join(myArray3, "|")`, or to obtain the first missing element: `Debug.Print "Missing element: " & MyArray1(Application.match("x", myArray3, 0))`, which will return the first "x", first missing element...

Comment: I can also place such a "comprehensive" answer, but the comments before mine one already clarified the main issue. I only tried emphasizing some aspects to make the issue clearer. Otherwise, placing a more elaborated answer (which may contain more examples) looks to take from the above comments issuers credit... They already answered the main aspect, as I said in my first sentence and I thought that placing an answer is not so appropriate. **If you insist to receive a more elaborated answer** I can do it. Not right now, anyhow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two using ways is the fact that `WorksheetFunction` raises a **fatal error**, stopping on the respective yellow code line and `Application` **does not**, in the same circumstances, if any error occurs.

In case of `WorksheetFunction`, you can handle the errors only using `On Error Resume Next`, which limits the possibility of using the function return and it is not so elegant, too.

In some (rare) cases the return of the same function used in both ways **is different**. My following answer will not refer to these peculiarities, it will show an example of raised errors for both cases, but mainly be focused on advantages and possibilities created by using `Application` instead of `WorksheetFunction`:

If you use: `Debug.Print WorksheetFunction.VLookup("code",A2:F1000,3, False)` it will offer intellisense suggestions, but will raise a run-time error ('1004'): 'Unable to get the VLookup property of WorksheetFunction class', if no any match of `Lookup_value` in `Table_array`.

Using

```
Debug.Print Application.VLookup("code",A2:F1000,3, False) 'does not raise a run-time error
'it will return Error 2042
```

It does  not look as a big deal at the first glance, but it opens a lot of possibilities to use that different way of behaving.

Let us study a very versatile function: `Match`

I will not use the `WorksheetFunction` case, which will all the time raise a run-time error if not a match. I will focus only on `Application.Match` advantages:

```
Sub testApplicationMatchAdvantages()
  Dim ret, arr
  arr = Array(1, 3, 6, 9, 11)
  arr = Split("1, 3, 6, 9, 11", ", ")
  ret = Application.match("5", arr, 0)
  If IsError(ret) Then Debug.Print "5" & " does not exist in the array...": 'Exit Sub
  ret = Application.match("9", arr, 0)
  If IsNumeric(ret) Then
    Debug.Print 9 & " is the " & ret & "th element of the array and it will be removed:"
    arr = filter(arr, arr(ret - 1), False) 'arr(ret)-1 because arr is zero based
    Debug.Print Join(arr, "|") '9 has been removed
  Else
    Debug.Print 9 & " does not exist in the array...": Exit Sub
  End If
  Dim arr2, arr3
  arr2 = Array(1, 3, 4, 9)
  arr2 = Split("1, 4, 3, 9", ", ")
  arr3 = Application.IfError(Application.match(arr2, arr, 0), "X")
  
  Debug.Print Join(arr3, "|") 'meaning that the first element in arr2 matches the first one in arr
                              'and the third one, matches the second of arr
  'using:
  arr3 = Application.match(arr2, arr, 0) 'it returns a 1 based array, but it cannot be returned by joinning
                                         ' because of Error 2042 elements
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr3)
    Debug.Print arr3(i);
  Next i
End Sub
```

You can also play with `Application.Index`, `Application.VLookup` which are also able to return arrays to play width.

In conclusion, `Application` overpass the run-time fatal errors and offers many possibilities to use the return. Being an error or not, being an array containing error number elements. Which cannot be handled using `WorksheetFunction`...

Comment: If I have used like this `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose` , in that case it behaves as **Application** or **WorksheetFunction**

Comment: @Soma It behaves as `WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: About speed comparison, Is both of them (`Application.Function` and `WorksheetFunction.Function`) the same speed?

Comment: @Soma AFAIK, both of them use similar internal algorithms, so they should have a similar speed. But `the function you want using (`Transpose`) has its limitations in  number of rows to be processed. A custom transpose function/sub can overpass this limitation and using arrays, the speed can be similar, too.